# What is the X-FB-DEBUG header returned from Facebook?

Tags: ajax, facebook, header, facebook-javascript-sdk, jsonp

I'm wondering what the header mentioned above is. It's included in the response when I do JSONP calls to Facebook, or even when I simply access http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/

I haven't found any documentation on facebook, e.g. on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/etags-reference/

So, hope somebody can help me. thx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To me, this seems to be a request tracking id, so that Facebook can find and trace an specific request details [faster] when you fill in a bug report. Have seen them in lots of bug reports on their bug tracker.

Answer (score 10):

A little late, but just to add more information that I think it's useful. Facebook has now a place for it in its documentation, we can find it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v1.0)

> If you need to report a bug in the Graph API, we include a couple of additional request headers that you should send with your bug report to help us pinpoint and reproduce your issue. These request headers are X-FB-Debug and x-fb-rev.