# If I have X-FB-Debug id, can Facebook help me?

Tags: facebook

I am having an ongoing issue with Facebook not liking the response it gets back from my server.  I would assume that somewhere Facebook has logs that might provide clues as to what the issue is with the response.  Does Facebook have a way, other than the Bug Reporting mechanism, to request errors from their server logs matching my X-FB-Debug Id or AppId?

Possible? Probable? Likely?

Surely someone must know what this X-FB-Debug number is for, but I'm not finding references to this.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612794/what-is-the-x-fb-debug-header-returned-from-facebook/16179559 ?

Comment: I disagree.  That question you refer to is why I worded the question the way I did.  Someone says they see them in bug reports, but I'm asking if there is another way to engage Facebook with the ID, to help troubleshoot an issue that may lie on our end, not necessarily being a bug on the Facebook end.

Comment: I guess the sole purpose is "What is X-FB-DEBUG used for?". Not being stubborn on that, though.